# os.stat(path) TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to pass the name of a file in the entry and check whether the given file exists or not in the given path. However, I am getting the above error.

```py
def save_info():
    result = os.path.exists(filename_entry)

filename= Label(text="Enter the name of the file:")
filename.grid(row=1,column=0)

filename= StringVar()

filename_entry= Entry(textvariable="filename",width=30)

filename_entry.grid(row=4)
```

Comment: `os.path.exists(filename_entry.get())`?

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = os.path.exists(filename_entry)
```

As rightly pointed out by @MZ,

`os.path.exists()` accepts a string not a widget!

`filename_entry` is a entry widget to get its content (string) you need to use the `.get()` method

```py
result = os.path.exists(filename_entry.get())
```

You can read more about entry boxes [here](https://tkdocs.com/widgets/entry.html)